# How to disable source code downloading for Gitlab-CI job?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have .gitlab-ci.yml file with job inside it (with Win Runner, but it doesn't matter in my question):

```
runWin:
    stage: runOnWin
    tags: ['WinRunner']
    rules:
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $jobbranch
    script: |
        echo "WinRunner job started %CI_JOB_NAME%"
        dir
```

It works fine, but gitlab-runner downloads source code from git, but really I don't need it at all. Can I write some command or keywords to prevent it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can set a variable to disable git checkout called `GIT_STRATEGY` see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#configure-runner-behavior-with-variables

when you set `GIT_STRATEGY` to none, the runner will not try to download your git repository.

```yaml
runWin:
    variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: none
    stage: runOnWin
    tags: ['WinRunner']
    rules:
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $jobbranch
    script: |
        echo "WinRunner job started %CI_JOB_NAME%"
        dir
```

Comment: A lot of thanks! It's great!